# Javascript doesn't play the element arraylist when it reaches, how come?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really stuck on playing audio list randomly after a certain index. I'm trying to make my program play audio sequently starting at index 0(after clicking the button). When the index increments to 4, it would still play the array element 4 but the duration time will depend on the user's selection before clicking the play button, which is what I did using document.getElementById. And when the index i = 5, I wanna make the program randomly choose the element from 5 to 8 and play it. The duration time will still depend on user's selection in the first place(before clicking the play button).

Below is my code so far. It's not working. It will start playing randomly element when i increments to 4. I just read that JavaScript is 1 thread to run entire program. Is so, how should handle this problem?

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it a lot.

Note: the numFollowUpQuest variable is how many times the user wants to be given question.

```
var intro_playList = [{
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "0_silence"
    }, {
        "duration": 500,
        "key": "1_hello"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "2_how_old"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "3_what_did_you_make"
    }, {
        // story_playlist
        "duration": 1000,
        //"duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "4_tell_me_a_story"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        //"duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "5_and_then_what"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "6_why"
    }];

<select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Number of follow-up questions</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Second between each question</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');           
    audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio);
    var i = 0;

$("#play").on("click", playAudio);

        function playAudio() {
            console.log(i);
            var audioIndex = intro_playList[i++];
            console.log(audioIndex);
            console.log("After " + audioIndex.duration + " seconds play next audio");

            audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
            audioElement.load();
            setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);

            if(i === 4){
                intro_playList[i].duration = document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000;

                audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                audioElement.load();
                console.log(audioElement);
                setTimeout(function(){ audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);
            } else if(i >= 5){
                intro_playList[i].duration = document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000;
                audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                audioElement.load();
                setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);

                // Start randomly picking
                var numFollowUpQuest = document.getElementById("numFollowUp").value;

                for(numFollowUpQuest; numFollowUpQuest >= 1; numFollowUpQuest--){

                    var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((8 - 4) + 1) + 4);
                    console.log("randomInt is " + randomInt);                        
                    audioElement.src = "sound/" + intro_playList[randomInt].key + ".wav";

                    console.log(audioElement);
                    audioElement.load();
                    setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);
                }
            }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely this line in your `playAudio` function:

```
console.log(i); // i === 0
var audioIndex = intro_playList[i++]; // i === 1
```

The increment operator `++` modifies its operand *in place*, so `i++` is equivalent to

```
i = i + 1;
```

All your subsequent uses of `i` in that function will be 1 more than whatever was logged to the console. So `i` will in effect never be 0, and if you're seeing 4 in the console you've actually got 5 by the time it does anything.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Jared. But if I don't increment in the intro_playList, where should I increment? I tried everywhere before the if statement (i ===4), it still skips the 4th element and plays the 5th element

Comment: @Johnny I'd increment at the very end of the function, on a line by itself `++i;`

Comment: I just figured that out as well but I still do i+=1. It works fine. At this point, I don't understand what different between put the increment before the if statement and after? Could you explain this, please?

Comment: @Johnny Because the value of `i` *changes* when you assign to it. If you put it at the beginning of the function then for instance i will never be 0 when it hits the `if` or when it is used to index the `intro_playList` array.